# Which mapping type to choose for associative Arrays? Doctrine ODM

Tags: arrays, doctrine, mongodb, associative

I have a simple question about the (by the way really great!) Doctrine ODM.

Assume you have a document like:

```
/**
 * @Document
 */
class Test
{
    /** @Id */
    public $id;
    /** @WHICHTYPE */
    public $field = array();
}
```

Now i want to store an associative array like

```
array("test" => "test1", "anothertest" => "test2", ......);
```

In the $field property of that class.

No problem for MongoDB, I know, but in Doctrine when I use for example @Collection or simply @Field, only the values are stored (array_values is being used in the mapping driver for collection for example). So the stored value looks like

```
array("test1", "test2", ....)
```

Does anyone know which Doctrine-ODM mapping type I should use in order to preserve the key-value pairs in the database?

Thank you in advance,

Andi (greetz from germany)

Answer (score 18):

It should be the Hash type:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=hash#hash

Answer (score 1):

For versions before ODM 2.0 @Hash will provide the necessary data type. However after ODM 2.0 @Hash field is being removed. In order to use it we have to use @field with type hash. 
For further reference `[click here][1]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `hash` data type. Aren't you?

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @Document
 */
class Test
{
    /** @Id */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="hash")
    */
    public $field;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is using [hash type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types). But if for some reason you wantn't use `hash` type, you can use EmbeddedDocument feature provided by Doctrine ODM like the documentation says:

> If you are using the hash type, values within the associative array
>   are passed to MongoDB directly, without being prepared. Only formats
>   suitable for the Mongo driver should be used. If your hash contains
>   values which are not suitable you should either use an embedded
>   document or use formats provided by the MongoDB driver (e.g.
>   \MongoDate instead of \DateTime).

So, you need to create EmbeddedDocument `EmbeddedExample` in `AppBundle\Document\EmbeddedExample.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class EmbeddedExample
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     */
    protected $some_name;

    // ...
    // getter and setter
}
```

Then, you can use `EmbeddedExample` in your `Test` document. So the `Test.php` file will be similar to this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TestRepository")
*/
class Test
{

    /** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="EmbeddedExample") */
    private $field;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -5):

@Array should work. At least an equivalent exists in the ORM (@Column(type="array"))

Comment: this is a real useless answer