# Doctrine ORM entity with ODM mixed relation

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In relation to [Doctrine ODM and schema-less design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306622/doctrine-odm-and-schema-less-design):

I have a Product entity class with a variable set of attributes, i'd like to use MongoDB to store those. Now here's my problem:

I know that I can reference to a Mongo Document by using https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/references.md

But, then I'd have a empty document class with only 1 class property with the "@hash" annotation.. and my path will look something like this: "$product->getAttributeSet()->getAttributes()", assuming my Document is named "AttributeSet".

Is there a prettier/better way of doing this?

Comment: You could use magic `__get()`, `__set()`, `__call()` to "hide" attributeSet.